# Prawn: conditional text for multiple page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, prawn, prawnto

I can generate a pdf in prawn. I need to show some text if the generated pdf is multipage. For example, if generated pdf is more than one page, then I have to show "continued ..." in all pages except last page. And if the pdf is just one page then I don't want to show it at all. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should work:

```
if (num_pages = pdf.page_count) > 1
  pdf.repeat(lambda { |pg| pg < num_pages }) do
    pdf.draw_text "continued...", :at => [250, 20]
  end
end
```

Comment: You don't need the `if` clause. `pg < num_pages` ensures that it never prints on the last page. A one-page document has only one page which is also the last page. `1 < 1` is false.

Answer (score 1):

[Prawn's `repeat`](http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Document.html#method-i-repeat) can print text on any selection of pages. The first argument takes a named key, an array, a range or a lambda. In your case, you can define all pages except the last as a range.

```
page_range = (1..(pdf.page_count - 1))
pdf.repeat(page_range) do
  pdf.draw_text "continued ..."
end
```